# Purpose of NUL character in Bitlocker recovery text file

Tags: encryption, bitlocker, ascii, textfiles

I was setting up BitLocker today and my recovery text file looks like this:

[image: BitLocker recovery text file]

However, I tried to copy and paste this file into another document for backup purposes, and it came out looking like this:

`BitLocker Drive Encryption recovery key`

I.e. it got truncated after the first line. I noticed in Sublime Text there is actually a 'NUL' character at the end of the first line.

**Is this character intentionally inserted into these files to make it hard for users to copy and paste this information or does it serve some other purpose?**

Comment: This is a question only Microsoft can answer. We don't know why they put that there.

Comment: This sounds more like a case of encoding on the file being changed, and in doing so, this character shows up.  I assume that’s just a cat of the file in a command prompt?

Comment: No sorry @Ramhound - the program saves a text file to disk and I opened it in Sublime Text. Twisty - fair point, I guess I was wondering if any MSFT engineers might comment here, or someone else who might have used the same trick might comment.